# Meteor-React tutorial, can't see Mongo data in the web-browser

Tags: meteor, meteor-react

I'm trying to learn Meteor by meteor.com/tutorials/, I've completed blaze version - everything worked perfectly, and now when I tried React version (meteor.com/tutorials/react/collections). I had some issues with importing the collection.

After step 3.4 I do:

```
db.tasks.insert({ text: "Hello world!", createdAt: new Date() });
```

And then run meteor(sudo meteor run), application starts normally but in the web browser I can't see any data. Only background styles.

EDIT 1:

/imports/api/tasks.js

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
```

/imports/ui/App.JSX

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

import { Tasks } from '../api/tasks.js';

import Task from './Task.jsx';

// App component - represents the whole app
class App extends Component {
  renderTasks() {
    return this.props.tasks.map((task) => (
      <Task key={task._id} task={task} />
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <header>
          <h1>Todo List</h1>
        </header>

        <ul>
          {this.renderTasks()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  tasks: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default createContainer(() => {
  return {
    tasks: Tasks.find({}).fetch(),
  };
}, App);
```

/server/main.js

```
import '../imports/api/tasks.js';
```

( Here is GitHub repository with all modified files: https://github.com/brozermanik/meteor-rect-tutorial )

EDIT2: In the Mongo shell I've tried:

```
show dbs
```

And:

```
show collections
```

And it showed tasks db and its elements.

So either Meteor can't fetch data from Mngo or there's something wrong with the rendering component.

Sorry, if this is too newbie question but I've been stuck for 3 days already.

Comment: You should paste the relevant code here instead of just linking to your repo. Moreover, could you tell us what you have tried so far and if you have narrowed down the problem at all? See more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thx for answer, i tried to correct my question.

Comment: Nice. I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code. Are you sure you still have the `autopublish` package? (Run `meteor list` to find out) Have you tried to access the collection on the browser JS console?

Comment: Yeah, i have autopublish 1.07. But i can't acces on browser: VM1561:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: tasks is not defined (Tasks also)

Comment: Do `var Tasks = require('/imports/api/tasks.js').Tasks` in the browser console and then try `Tasks.find().fetch()`

Answer (score 0):

In server/main.js, you should put

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
  Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
});
```

I think the issue is that you'd put it in client/main.js !